# How can I send a message to a Telegram channel if they entered via the invitation via my bot they entered via the invitation via my bot

Tags: join, bots, telegram

I do it my bot to bot father and manybots. Someone can join to my telegram

```
/invite
```

simple question, and get the `t.me/link`.

Click and done here but I want to my bot write hello @username
and if the user invite someone get ban both user

I couldn't try because I don't know where to start, I have a working invite bot